# color code text box in SSRS report based on date range

Tags: reporting-services

i'm trying to color code a text box in Report based on date range. when i run below expression i'm getting error

> The Background Color expression for the text box ‘NSIXMONTH’ contains
> an error: [BC30198] ')' expected.
> "

Can anyone please help.

```
=IIF( IsNothing(Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value), "Transparent"
    ,IIF (Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value <=  DATEADD("D", -( DAY( Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value), Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value), "RED"
        , IIF ( TODAY() > = DATEADD("MM", DATEDIFF ( "MM", 0 , Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value),0) 
                     AND  
                                     TODAY() < = DATEADD ( "D", -1, DATEADD ( "MM", DATEDIFF("MM", 0, Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value) +1 ,0)),"YELLOW,"Transparent" ))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an right parenthesis in the first DATEADD's second argument  `-( DAY( Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value)`

It's easier to find issues like this if you use line breaks and tabs to format the expression

```
=IIF( IsNothing(Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value), 
    "Transparent" ,
    IIF (Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value <= DATEADD("D", - DAY( Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value), Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value), 
        "RED" , 
        IIF ( TODAY() > = DATEADD("MM", DATEDIFF ( "MM", 0 , Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value),0) AND TODAY() < = DATEADD ( "D", -1, DATEADD ( "MM", DATEDIFF("MM", 0, Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value) +1 ,0)),
            "YELLOW,
            "Transparent" 
            )
        )
    )
```

But with multiple conditions, it's even easier to use the SWITCH statement. The SWITCH evaluates the first expression and if true returns the 2nd argument. If False, it goes the Argument 3 and so on.

```
=SWITCH( IsNothing(Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value), "Transparent" ,
        Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value <= DATEADD("D", 0 - DAY(Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value), Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value), "RED" , 
        TODAY() > = DATEADD("MM", DATEDIFF ( "MM", 0 , Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value),0) AND TODAY() < = DATEADD ( "D", -1, DATEADD ( "MM", DATEDIFF("MM", 0, Fields!NSIXMONTH.Value) +1 ,0)), "YELLOW,
        1 = 1, "Transparent" 
        )
```